# Need to move logo on site using WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am having trouble aligning my logo on a page I am making in WordPress.

I would like the logo to be of the same height as the store hours that are on the right, and aligned to the left border of the ribbon.

Here is my relevant PHP code:

```
<!-- Favicon -->
       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/favicon.ico">

       <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />


        <?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>


          <?php
      $g =  of_get_option('google_analytics', '' );
      if (!empty($g)){
    ?>
      <script type="text/javascript"><?php echo $g; ?></script>
<?php } ?>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span7 logo">
  <?php $image1 = of_get_option('logo', '' ); 
if($image1 != "") : ?>
        <h1 id="logo"><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image1; ?>" alt=""/></a></h1>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div><!--end logo--> 
        <div class="span5 open-hours">
         <?php  /* Widgetized sidebar, if you have the plugin installed. */
                    if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('OpenHours') ) : ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!--end open-hours-->
```

Below is my relevant CSS code:

```
@import "css/shortcodes.css";

/* RESET STYLES */
*, html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, label, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, th, td { margin:0; padding:0 }
table { border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0 }
fieldset, img { border:0 }
address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var { font-style:normal; font-weight:normal }
ol, ul, li { list-style:none }
caption, th { text-align:left }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-weight:normal;padding-bottom:10px;}
q:before, q:after { content:''}
strong { font-weight: bold }
em { font-style: italic }
.italic { font-style: italic }
.aligncenter { display:block; margin:0 auto; }
.alignleft { float:left; margin:10px; }
.alignright { float:right;margin:10px; }
.no-margin{margin:0px;}
.no-bottom{margin-bottom:0px;}
.no-padding{padding:0px;}
.margin-t{margin-top:25px;}
div { position:relative } 
a{text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
a:active,a:focus{outline: none;}


div,img{ 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

/**** GENERAL STYLES*****/
html{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}
.wrap,.wrap-slider, .wrap-header, .wrap-content,.top-img,#footer{width:980px;margin:0 auto;}
.wrap-content{ background:#fff;padding:20px 0;}
.wrap-slider, .wrap-header{background:#fff;margin-bottom: 20px;}
.wrap-header{margin-top:20px;padding:20px 0;}

.wrapper_food ul{margin-bottom:10px;}
.wrapper_food ul li, .circle li{ background: url("images/circle.png") no-repeat scroll 0 9px transparent;padding: 3px 0 3px 15px;}

h1{font-size: 42px; line-height:42px;}
h2{font-size:36px;line-height:36px;}
h3{font-size:30px;line-height:30px;}
h4{font-size:24px;line-height:24px;}
h5{font-size:18px;line-height:18px;}
h6{font-size:12px;line-height:12px;}
h1, h2{margin-bottom:12px;}
h3, h4, h5, h6{margin-bottom:6px;}
p{margin-bottom:18px;}
.column-clear{clear:both;}
.clear{overflow: hidden;}
/**** END GENERAL STYLES*****/
/**** HEADER STYLES*****/
.open-hours{margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px;font-family: 'Merienda One', cursive;padding-left:130px;}
.open-title{font-size:18px;margin-bottom:6px;padding:0;}
.open-day{margin-bottom:6px;}
#menu-holder{margin:0px auto;width:1000px;height:61px;z-index:999;}
.menu{margin: 0px auto;width: 1000px;height: 61px;z-index:999;position:absolute;}
.menu li {padding: 0px 2px 0px 0px; float: left; position: relative; text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;font-size:18px;line-height:1;}
.menu li a {padding:21px 25px 22px 25px;color: #ffffff;display:block;text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.6);}
.menu ul { background: #ffffff; display: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 180px; position: absolute; top: 61px; left: 0px;}
.menu ul li {display:block; float: none; margin: 0px 10px; padding:10px 0px;border-bottom:1px solid #f0f0f0;background:none;}
.menu ul li:last-child{border:none;}
.menu ul li:hover a, .menu li:hover li a, .menu ul li.sfHover a, .menu li.sfHover li a { background:none;color:#d5d5d5;border:none;}
.menu li:hover li:hover a, .menu li.sfHover li.sfHover a{color:#353535;}
.menu li:hover > ul, .menu li.sfHover > ul { display: block;}
.menu ul a{font-size: 13px; padding:0px;text-transform:uppercase;width:180px;display:block;height:auto;text-shadow:none;}
.menu ul ul { left: 190px; top:5px; }
.menu .sub-menu li.current_page_item a { color: #353535; }
.mobile-navigation {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    color: #8F8F8F;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
}

/**** END HEADER STYLES*****/
```

Can anyone see what is the relevant code I need to modify in order to adjust the position and size of the logo?

Comment: Can you provide an image with arrows or an example of what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove margin-top: 30px from open-hours. Or alternatively add the same margin for your logo.

This was easy to see using Chrome developer tools. If you are unfamiliar, in Chrome try view > developer > developer tools. Then in the bottom left corner, click on the magnifying glass icon. Then you can click on the opening hours and on the logo and see from "computed style" on the right that their upper margins are different.